# Javascript query string not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script>// <![CDATA[
$(function(){
  var currentPostUrl = window.location.href + "?ref=blogshare"
  var currentPostTitle = $('.post-title').text().trim();

  $('#myModal').appendTo("body") 

  var facebookShareUrl = "https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=" + currentPostUrl
  var emailShareUrl = "mailto:?to=&body=Hey, I thought you might like this post. It's called " + currentPostTitle + ". You can read it here:  " + currentPostUrl + "&subject=Thought you might like this post..."


  $('.email-share').attr('href', emailShareUrl);

// ]]></script>
```

The goal of the above script is to get the current url and append a ref query string to it. Then we change the href of a link to add a custom mailto.

The above seems to work perfectly fine on desktop. But on mobile (chrome iphone), when I click the email-share link, the ?ref=blogshare is not being appended to the link.

Any ideas why?

Comment: You need use encodeURIComponent...

Comment: That was it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to encode querystring values.

[`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

```
var currentPostUrl = encodeURIComponent(window.location.href + "?ref=blogshare");
```